# Gitlab - gitlab-ci.yml is not recognizing 7zip command

Tags: msbuild, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, 7zip

I just started using Gitlab's CI/CD feature. I need to create the zip file for the published items. The last two lines of the **script** should do the magic.

```
    build:
        stage: build
        script:
            - echo "Testing CI CD"
            - git clone https://gitlab.io/common-dependencies.git
            - git clone https://gitlab.io/sitecore-nuget.git
            - nuget restore
            - msbuild Common.SC.sln /property:Configuration=Release
/p:PublishProfile=C:\CICDArtifacts\Artifacts_Release.pubxml


            - cd .\bin\Release
            - '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a C:\CICDArtifacts\$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_JOB_ID.zip'
```

But when the build triggers, i get the following error.

[image]

However when i executed below command in Gitlab runner it runs perfectly.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a C:\CICDArtifacts\commonProject.zip'
```

It looks like i'm missing something here. Please help me to understand, how gitlab runner understands commands  like `7z` , `echo`, `msbuild` etc.

Please note that, 7zip is installed and it is located under
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe

Your help much appreciated.

Comment: try the command without the quotes. `- C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a C:\CICDArtifacts\commonProject.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the problem using below steps.

- updated `%PATH%` environment variable pointing to 7z.exe path.
- Updated the script as below.

  '- 7z a C:\CICDArtifacts\$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_JOB_ID.zip'
- Restarted the Gitlab runner as, Gitlab was not able to recognize the `7z` command after updating the environment variables.

Hope it is helpful for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

> how gitlab runner understands commands like echo, msbuild etc

It should understand them if their parent folder is in the `%PATH%`.

If running the command without quotes does not work, try the alternative script line:

```
- cmd /C "\""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a C:\CICDArtifacts\commonProject.zip"
```

The without quotes form would be: no single quotes:

```
- "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a C:\CICDArtifacts\commonProject.zip
```

Comment: Thanks for making me understand on "how gitlab runner understands commands like echo, msbuild etc", with that information i'm able to resolve the issue. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
- powershell -Command executable.exe arguments
```

This command has worked for me to kickoff an exe in gitlab yaml.

Answer (score 0):

For my case I did a `choco install 7zip.install` and somehow I was able to use `7z` in `gitlab-ci-yml`